# Inserting text from VBA UserForm textbox into part of a string

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox, userform

A date will be entered by the user into UserForm TEXTBOX1 which will be placed at a bookmark in the document.

```vb
.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK1").Range _
.InsertBefore TEXTBOX1
```

I have option buttons for the user to select, which will place specific text into the document as follows:

```vb
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
If Me.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BOOKMARK2").Range
    oRng.Text = "EXAMPLE SENTENCE 1" & Chr(11) & Chr(9) & _
                "EXAMPLE SENTENCE 2" & Chr(11) & _
                "EXAMPLE SENTENCE 3" & vbNewLine & " "
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "BOOKMARK2", oRng
End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to get the date in TEXTBOX1 to appear at the end of `"EXAMPLE SENTENCE 2"` before the `& CHR(11) &`.

Comment: Cross-posted -with a detailed answer - at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?70435-Inserting-text-from-VBA-textbox-into-part-of-a-string&p=417787#post417787. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"EXAMPLE SENTENCE 2" & TEXTBOX1.Text & Chr(11)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim. This method works perfectly!